# Apollo mixes two different arrays of the same query seemingly at random

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, react-apollo

With a schema like

```
schema {
  query: QueryRoot
}

scalar MyBigUint

type Order {
  id: Int!
  data: OrderCommons!
  kind: OrderType!
}

type OrderBook {
  bids(limit: Int): [Order!]!
  asks(limit: Int): [Order!]!
}

type OrderCommons {
  quantity: Int!
  price: MyBigUint! // where it doesn't matter whether it's MyBigUint or a simple Int - the issue occurs anyways
}

enum OrderType {
  BUY
  SELL
}

type QueryRoot {
  orderbook: OrderBook!
}
```

And a query `query { orderbook { bids { data { price } }, asks { data { price } } } }`

In a graphql playground of my graphql API (and on the network level of my Apollo app too) I receive a result like

```
{
  "data": {
    "orderbook": {
      "bids": [
        {
          "data": {
            "price": "127"
          }
        },
        {
          "data": {
            "price": "74"
          }
        },
        ...
      ],
      "asks": [
        {
          "data": {
            "price": "181"
          }
        },
        {
          "data": {
            "price": "187"
          }
        },
        ...
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

where, for the purpose of this question, the bids are ordered in descending order by price like ["127", "74", "73", "72"], etc, and asks are ordered in ascending order, accordingly.

However, in Apollo, after a query is done, I notice that one of the arrays gets seemingly random data.

For the purpose of the question, useQuery react hook is used, but the same happens when I query imperatively from a freshly initialized `ApolloClient`.

```
  const { data, subscribeToMore, ...rest } = useQuery<OrderbookResponse>(GET_ORDERBOOK_QUERY);
  console.log(data?.orderbook?.bids?.map(r => r.data.price));
  console.log(data?.orderbook?.asks?.map(r => r.data.price));
```

Here, corrupted data of Bids gets printed i.e. `['304', '306', '298', '309', '277', '153', '117', '108', '87', '76']` (notice the order being wrong, at the least), whereas Asks data looks just fine. Inspecting the network, I find that Bids are not only properly ordered there, but also have different (correct, from DB) values!

Therefore, it seems something's getting corrupted on the way while Apollo delivers the data.

What could be the issue here I wonder, and where to start debugging such kind of an issue? There seem to be no warnings from Apollo either, it seems to just silently corrupt the data.

I'm clearly doing something wrong, but what?

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to stem from how Apollo caches data.

My Bids and Asks could have the same numeric IDs but share the same Order graphql type. Apollo rightfully assumes a Bid and an Ask with the same ID are the same things and the resulting data gets wrecked as a consequence.

An easy fix is to show Apollo that there's a complex key to the Order type on cache initialization:

```
cache: new InMemoryCache({
    typePolicies: {
      Order: {
        keyFields: ['id', 'kind'],
      }
    }
  })
```

This way it'll understand that the Order entities Ask and Bid with the same ID are different pieces of data indeed.

Note that the field kind should be also added to the query strings accordingly.